# How to rewrite nested loops in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an ugly for loop that I would like to rewrite into lodash. I have an array (allData) which contains an array (grp1) which contains an array (grp2) etc. eg:;

```
       (4) [grp, grp, grp, grp]  //the allData Array

        0: grp                   // eg the 0 pointer
           grp1: Array(4)        // have grp1 Array in it
           ..
           0: grp1               // eg the 0 pointer
              grp2: Array(4)     // have grp1 Array in it
              ..
              0: grp3 {}         // grp3 have now the id
              1: grp3
                 id: (...)
                 color: (...)
```

I write an for loop and nested it. It works but in my opionion the code is ugly.

```
   for (let grp1 of allData) {
        for (let grp2 of grp1.getIdsForGrp1()) {
            for (let grp3 of grp2.getIdsForGrp2()) {
               if searchID === grp3.id {
                return grp3.id
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

It is possible to rewrite it with lodash?

Comment: You would like to get all `id` in all groups, no matter how deep it nested or you only need some special level `id`s ?

Comment: show you allData as json or js object because is unclear what is your input data

Comment: sry the example I wrote is really bad. I'll add a better example later

Answer (score 1):

Bit difficult to give an answer just based on incomplete data, but you might want to do something like

```
const _ = require(lodash);

_(allData).flattenDeep().find(({id}) => id === searchID);
```

This assumes that the field 'id' is unique on the requested level (grp3) and is not present in the the first 2 levels (grp1 and grp2).

Hope this helps.